# Failed to load ApplicationContext for Junit test and Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, junit4

I want to test my service using JUnit,I am getting some error like `Failed to load ApplicationContext` I tried to load spring configuration class using `@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class, 
classes={MvcConfiguration.class})`.I kept bussiness classes and spring configuration class in `src/main/java` folder and my test classes in `src/test/java` folder even i tried to put `MvcConfiguratio`n class in `src/test/java` folder as well but it didn't work out shows same problem again

This is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class, 
classes={MvcConfiguration.class})
public class ServiceTest {
    @Autowired
   private EmployeeService empService;
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(21, empService.employeeCount());
    }
    @BeforeClass
    public static void serviceIntaciation(){
        System.out.println("beforeclass");
    }

}
```

Trace

```
May 29, 2017 6:22:30 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
May 29, 2017 6:22:30 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@2133c8f8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@43a25848, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3ac3fd8b, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@5594a1b5, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@6a5fc7f7, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@3b6eb2ec]
beforeclass
May 29, 2017 6:22:30 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3ac3fd8b] to prepare test instance [org.gov.mord.nrlm.test.ServiceTest@13fee20c]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load WebApplicationContext from non-web merged context configuration [MergedContextConfiguration@64616ca2 testClass = ServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class org.gov.mord.nrlm.test.MvcConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader', parent = [null]]. Consider annotating your test class with @WebAppConfiguration.
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: have you tried to follow the stacktrace advise?
"Consider annotating your test class with @WebAppConfiguration."

Comment: @llya  thanks for helping me out  _@WebAppConfiguration_ works for me. in addition I need to change the version of 'javax.servlet-api' version from 2.0.4 to 3.0.1 in pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I received this java.lang.IllegalStateException when I tried running some tests but hadn't fully refreshed the project (someone else had checked in a change that I needed). If you're working on a team, ensure that you have refreshed and gotten latest. 
Oddly enough, the tests ran via command line (mvn test) but failed inside Eclipse.